# Python how to pull string out of QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to pull a string from a QDateTimeEdit.  I have tried several things and I keep getting different errors or I just get the memory location. I need it to put into a SQlite search string.

```
self.StartTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.widget)
self.StartTime.setCalendarPopup(True)
self.StartTime.setObjectName("StartTime")
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.StartTime, 0, 0, 1, 3)
self.StartTime.setDate(QDate(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7)))
self.StartTime.setTime(QTime.currentTime())

#This doesn't work
#print(self.StartTime.sectionText())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the date-time stored in the `QDateTimeEdit`, the first thing to do is get it through `dateTime()` and then convert it to string with `toString()` indicating the appropriate format, if you want to obtain with the current format you can use `displayFormat()`

```
dt = self.StartTime.dateTime()
# dt.toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss.zzz"))
dt_string = dt.toString(self.StartTime.displayFormat())
print(dt_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a champ. I would have thought It would of had a toString method.Thanks!